# Method not found: 'System.String Automation.get_MachineName()'

Tags: xdb, mongodb

I'm trying to get a newly built Sitecore 8.2 working on my computer. The code compiles, but when I try to load the site it shows the error

```
Method not found: 'System.String Automation.get_MachineName()'.
```

Full stack trace:

> [MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.String Automation.get_MachineName()'.]
>      Sitecore.Analytics.Automation.AutomationWorker.Start() +0
>      (Object , Object[] ) +71
>      Sitecore.Pipelines.PipelineMethod.Invoke(Object[] parameters) +36
>      Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +365
>      Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +162
>      Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +18
>      Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args) +18
>      Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args) +49
>      Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Application_Start() +156
>      Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Init(HttpApplication app) +472
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +536
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +173
>      System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +336
>      System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +296
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Method not found: 'System.String Automation.get_MachineName()'.]
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +10043436
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +95
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254

Comment: Recently upgraded the solution?

Comment: Yep. It was on Sitecore 6.5, a separate agency upgraded the solution to 8.2 and now I have their source code which I'm trying to get working.

Comment: Pretty sure there are some mismatched DLLs in play here. Try removing anything sitecore from your bin directory and putting in a vanilla set from the 8.2 original archive. That said - there could also be 6.5 configuration files left over.